# Building v8 on ubuntu (docker)

Tags: ubuntu, v8

I try to build v8 on ubuntu (using docker because I don't have root access on my dev environment).

I try to follow the instruction here https://github.com/v8mips/v8mips/wiki/Get-the-code

I can get the `depot_tools` but when I run `fetch v8`, I get the following error:

```
Error: Command '/usr/bin/python v8/third_party/binutils/download.py' 
    returned non-zero exit status 1 in /home
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 300, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 295, in main
    return run(options, spec, root)
  File "/home/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 289, in run
    return checkout.init()
  File "/home/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 132, in init
    self.run_gclient(*sync_cmd)
  File "/home/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 76, in run_gclient
    return self.run(cmd_prefix + cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/home/depot_tools/fetch.py", line 66, in run
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 574, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('gclient', 'sync', '--with_branch_heads')'
    returned non-zero exit status 2
```

Do anyone know what could be the issue? Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN apt-get install -y python
WORKDIR /home
RUN git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
ENV PATH /home/depot_tools:"$PATH"
```

I then run the docker with `docker run -it v8build` (name of the docker image) and run `fetch v8`

Edit (adding version info):

- Ubuntu: 16.04
- git: 2.7.4
- python: 2.7.12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured out what was the issue and here is the answer. Hopefully, someone would be able to benefit from it.

It turns out you can run `fetch -n v8` to see all the commands that will be run. And the commands are as follow:

```
fetch -n v8
Running: gclient root
Running: gclient config --spec 'solutions = [
  {
    "url": "https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git",
    "managed": False,
    "name": "v8",
    "deps_file": "DEPS",
    "custom_deps": {},
  },
]
'
Running: gclient sync --with_branch_heads
cd /home/x/v8
Running: git submodule foreach 'git config -f $toplevel/.git/config submodule.$name.ignore all'
Running: git config --add remote.origin.fetch '+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*'
Running: git config diff.ignoreSubmodules all
```

The error occurs at `gclient sync --with_branch_heads` as described by the error output.

I ran the commands one by one to replicate the process manually so it can print out messages that were hidden by running `fetch v8`.
And the error turns out to be that the `ubuntu:latest` docker image does not have `lbzip2`.

Installing that solves the issue.

Updated `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git python lbzip2 && apt-get clean
WORKDIR /home
RUN git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
ENV PATH /home/depot_tools:"$PATH"
RUN cd /home && fetch v8
```

The journey continues...